# Breakpoints in Views in Portable Areas are not hit while debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, portable-areas

We are using Portable Areas in our ASP.NET MVC web application, and I notice that breakpoints are not hit in Views that are contained in the Portable Area.

So I can not debug Views in a portable area, which is sometimes needed.

What could be solutions to this problem?

Things I already tried:

- Debug in VS2012 and VS2013
- Clear temporary asp.net files
- restart IIS
- restart PC
- Delete /bin/ and /obj/

**Breakpoints in the controller ARE hit.** Just not in the views so I suspect it has something to do with using portable areas.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. Here is what Visual Studio explains about the breakpoint:
[image: Portable View Breakpoint]

After disabling the option as suggested on the last line of the message I get this:
[image: Portable View Breakpoint]